# Show shipping block on magento checkout

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I would like to show the shipping block regardless if a price has been estimated or not. I have traced the methods back (seen below) but cannot figure out how to define the shipping block to load. I have some logic that is going in the view.

**Totals Template**: *frontend/site/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml*

**Shipping Template**: *frontend/site/default/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml*

The shipping block is rendered from the totals block by a renderTotals() method. It proceeds to check down the process of each possible total to determine if set.

**Totals Block**

```
<?php echo $this->rendeTotals(); ?>
```

The method refers to the Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals class with the following methods.

**Totals Controller (totals.php)**

```
 protected function _getTotalRenderer($code)
    {
        $blockName = $code.'_total_renderer';
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        if (!$block) {
            $block = $this->_defaultRenderer;
            $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode("global/sales/quote/totals/{$code}/renderer");
            if ($config) {
                $block = (string) $config;
            }

            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($block, $blockName);
        }
        /**
         * Transfer totals to renderer
         */
        $block->setTotals($this->getTotals());
        return $block;
    }

    public function renderTotal($total, $area = null, $colspan = 1)
    {
        $code = $total->getCode();
        if ($total->getAs()) {
            $code = $total->getAs();
        }
        return $this->_getTotalRenderer($code)
            ->setTotal($total)
            ->setColspan($colspan)
            ->setRenderingArea(is_null($area) ? -1 : $area)
            ->toHtml();
    }
```

Tracing up the stack it is easy to see that _getTotalRenderer is the actual method checking if the block is to be loading. It is in this method I am having trouble force loading the shipping block.

Any help is gratefully appreciated. Im have no development history inside magento.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i render the shipping block without defining pricing